# Availability Zone をまたぐ Floating IP の適用

Tags: aws

異なる Availability Zone (以降、AZ) に配置されている EC2インスタンス間で Active/Standby の冗長構成を組むため、AWS の Floating IP の使用を検討しています。
Floating IP は、Elastic IP (以降、EIP） の付け替えにより、アクティブのEC2 インスタンスを切り替える手法ですが、下記リンクの "利点" には、異なる AZ のインスタンスへ EIP の付け替えが可能とあり、"注意点" には、サブネットを超える EIP の付け替えはできないとあります。

[CDP:Floating IPパターン](http://aws.clouddesignpattern.org/index.php/CDP:Floating_IP%E3%83%91%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%B3)

私の理解では、サブネットが AZ をまたぐことはできないはずで、そうなると、AZ間で EIP の付け替えはできないということになってしまうと思いますが、この矛盾について何かご存知なことや参考ドキュメント等ありましたらご教示いただければと存じます。

Answer (score 0):

[その記事が書かれたのは2012年ごろ](http://aws.clouddesignpattern.org/index.php?title=CDP:Floating_IP%E3%83%91%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%B3&action=history)なので、過去の歴史を知るには参考になりますが、現代の設計にはあまりにも古すぎて役に立たないような気がします。